Ошибка команды pip install -r requirements.txt
я начинающий пользователь консоли termux. При установке инструмента nexfil, после того как всё прошло успешно, нужно ввести команду
pip install -r requirements.txt

возникает ошибка ERROR:

Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
1
Такой файл точно существует открывал его с помощью редакторов и находил путь, пробовал указать путь к этому файлу в самой команде выходит уже другая ошибка
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/data/data/com.termux/files/home'

Может кто подсказать решение?
Содержимое файла requirements.txt:



Что за nexfil, где его взять?

По-моему оно на содержание файла requirements.txt ругается. Покажите его.

Пишет, что нет такого файла requirements.txt. Если по полному пути устанавливать, то должен быть слеш между папкой и именем файла, а не пробел.

вторая ошибка говорит, что вы обращаетесь к директории, а не к файлу.

Пробовал обращаться к файлу через без пробела и со слешом высвечивается та же ошибка что и в первом случае

Ошибка возникает из-за адреса в 7 строке. Директория файла requirements.txt изначально была указана правильно:

Чтобы исправить ошибку, измените адреса зависимостей в файле requirements.txt, указав версии, например:
matplotlib==3.10.0rc1
pillow==11.0.0
asciinema==2.4.0
contourpy==1.3.1
cryptography==43.0.3
nump==2.1.3

Про "Electrum"-  подсказать не могу, есть несколько версий "Electrum"-а:


Большое вам спасибо всё получилось
